# Explicit cast of long/decimal to int

Tags: c#, casting, int, decimal, long-integer

Consider the following code:

```
long longMaxValue = long.MaxValue;
decimal decimalMaxValue = decimal.MaxValue;

int a = (int)longMaxValue;
int b = (int)decimalMaxValue;
```

Question #1: Why casting `longMaxValue` to `int` results in -1?

Question #2: Why casting `decimalMaxValue` to `int` results in the following exception BUT casting `longMaxValue` to `int` doesn't?

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. because `long.MaxValue` is binary 0111111....1111; casting here basically cuts it down to the last (least significant) 32 bits - all of which are 1; and binary 111...111 is: -1
2. integer arithmetic is `unchecked` in C# by default. Add `checked`, or change the compiler to check by default, and it will error

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Don't know about the `checked`/`unchecked` thing. Should check it out. But in the meantime, would be great if you could explain that concept in one sentence. Just to improve the answer.

Comment: Nothing changed, what am I doing wrong?
int b = (int)checked(decimalMaxValue);

Comment: @Anar `int b = checked((int)decimalMaxValue);` - the `checked` region needs to include the cast for it to be useful

Comment: @AnarKhalilov one sentence version of `checked` vs `unchecked`: in an `unchecked` context, integer overflows (including from conversions) are silently ignored; in a `checked` context: they aren't

Comment: Figured it out. Should've added `checked` to `a`, not `b`.
int a = checked((int)longMaxValue);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61673/discussion-between-anar-khalilov-and-marc-gravell).